# How to Force Eclipse to not Change Readonly File Flag?

Tags: eclipse

I'm using Eclipse with Perforce version control.  In P4V I check out the files I want to modify, making them readonly, but when I open a file I didn't check out in Eclipse it prompts me if I'd like to make it writable and defaults the anser to 'Yes.' If I'm not paying attention and just typing I unintentionally make files writable and then have to reconcile with P4V.

Is there any way to force Eclipse to just disallow changing the read-only flag on files?

Comment: wish i had a solution for this too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know the answer to your actual question, but you may be able to work around this issue by using Perforce's Eclipse plugin. That way, if you unintentionally modify a file, it will be in your pending CL where you can review the change and revert if it necessary.

http://www.perforce.com/perforce/products/p4eclipse.html

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse , click on Window-> preferences->Team->{selct ur source, in your case it should be P4V } . In there you have some default settings done. You can apply them as per your need. I had the same issue with MKS and me going there resolved the issue. 
MAKE SURE YOU REFRESH AND RESTART ECLIPSE TO SEE THE CHANGES. SOMETIMES ECLIPSE DOES NOT RECOGNIZE THE CHANGES MADE IN PREFERENCES.

I hope this helps you too.

Answer (score 0):

Setting **perforce_auto_checkout** property to **false** in Eclipse will give you the desired behaviour.